# Как отловить нажатие мимо диалога андроид

Tags: android, dialogfragment, dialog

Собственно есть DialogFragment и в нём много полей для ввода
Хочу что б если пользователь нажал мимо диалога
То перед закрытием спросить действительно ли он хочет его закрыть или это просто миссклик
Для этого нужно этот миссклик отловить
Но не нашёл как это сделать

Comment: Отлавливай любой клик по экрану.

Comment: Любой не катит
В диалоге есть списки, поля и кнопки

Comment: Клики по спискам, полям и кнопкам ловят сами поля и кнопки.

Comment: В фрагменте нету метода onTouch, а выносить это в активити странная практика
Еще решения?

Comment: dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

Comment: Наверное проще будет запретить такой способ закрытия: [`dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean)), а подтверждение, если хотите, повесить на оставшийся выход кнопкой `BACK`

Comment: Боюсь "проще" это не мой способ)

Comment: Тогда могу предложить переделать Ваш фрагмент с диалогом на активность в стиле диалога, а там уже больше возможностей. Тут есть пример отлова такого тача : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5831214 - надеюсь поможет.